# How to add container view on scrollview using constraint with item formate

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am new for auto-layouts and i am trying to add one `container view` on `ScrollView` using `auto-layouts` "`constraint with item`" formate but I can't adding using my code.

I know how to add using *visual* formate but I want to do  this process using `constraint with item` formate. Please help me!

### My code:

```
#import "ViewController3.h"

@interface ViewController3 ()
{
    UIScrollView * scrollView;
    UIView * containerView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController3


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

    //Applying autolayouts for scrollview
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    //Applying autolayouts for containerview
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Autolayout, you don't need to set scrollview's contentSize explicitly, but you have to provide enough clues to let Autolayout system infer what exactly your scrollview's contentSize is.

There are generally two ways to layout UIScrollView with Autolayout, mixed or pure Autolayout.Check this:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html.

If it is pure Autolayout, you can achieve that by your containerView's subviews, that is, your subviews do not rely on the scroll view to get their size. Or you can just tie your containerView's width and height to any view outside your scrollview, like self.view, or to a fixed value.

E.g,
You can add four more lines :

```
constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint2];
```